# Too low amount of calories?

Tags: calories

I am a 22 year old man who's looking to lose some body-fat while still maintaining/building muscle. I weight 90kg (200lbs), and my height is 184cm (6'0). I workout intensely 3 days a week.

I recently started counting calories, and figured that I have been consuming 1200 ish calories per day. Isn't this way too little? If I continue consuming 1200 calories a day, will I "tear down" muscle or something? How many calories should I try to consume per day?

Best regards, Eric.

Comment: A 200 pound person, working out 3 days a week, eating 1200 calories a day, will probably die from starvation.

Comment: I agree - with out training you are burning up to 2000 kcals. Workout - depends what is done, but can double that. So you are missing something...

Answer (score -1):

**You are probably counting it wrong.**

But hey, it is not your fault. There is no universal calorie measurement system for food. The numbers on the packages should only be used as guides, not as facts.

My experience so far says that Google calorie statistics are good approximations. Besides, calorie values suggested in products of larger companies are good as well. This observation is due to the fact that I lost weight when I was counting 1800/1900 and stopped losing weight when I increased it to 2100/2200. When I tried the same thing with products from smaller companies, I could not manage such a progress. I am 171 cm/66 kg.

If you had serious malnourishment, you would feel it. You would be sleep much longer hours, feel extremely exhausted, experience hair loss along with many other things.